# get access token using oauth in customer portal login site

Tags: customer-portal

I created customer portal login and site also. , i want to get access token using site url ...

my code is .....

```
<?php
session_start();
$token_url = "https://dinegane-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/services/oauth2/token";
$params = "&grant_type=password"
 &client_id=3MVG9Y6d_Btp4xp4_kyZjAflWPpJGKLI9bQAbo5OIx9oksL5UZQflN1NCM26aeC_AmFwZEAU4aHPoZghBZr4j"     
. "&client_secret=1688426240923908064"     
. "&username=xxxxxxxxxx"     
. "&password= xxxxxxxxx" ;   

$curl = curl_init($token_url);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$access_token = $response['access_token'];
$instance_url = $response['instance_url'];
echo "$json_response";
?>
```

.................................................................
I got error for this code plz anyone can guide me.....

error is ====
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"expired access/refresh token"}

thanks 
Ganez

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of the error seems that your refresh token has expired too. You need to obtain a new refresh token by setting the `grant_type` to `refresh_token` rather than `password`

EDIT:

You can find more detailed explanation [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_at_Salesforce.com#Token_Refresh)

Comment: how to get the refresh token tell me

Comment: As I said by setting the grant_type to refresh_token. Read the article that I've posted in the answer

Comment: hi @ e-bacho , I followed that link , i have got error msg "error=invalid_client_id&error_description=client%20identifier%20invalid"

Comment: Can you please check that the client id - `3MVG9Y6d_Btp4xp4_kyZjAflWPpJGKLI9bQAbo5OIx9oksL5UZQflN1NCM26aeC_AmFwZEAU4aHPoZghBZr4j` matches with the one specified in your organisation?

Comment: i checked my client id is same -

Comment: Are you testing this in sandbox by any chance? Because the link provided in your code `https://dinegane-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/services/oauth2/token` refers to a production instance by the looks of it...